# Prevent inline "waterproof" fuses from corroding

Tags: electrical, fuse, corrosion, water, boat

I recently bought a used aluminum boat that has 12v wiring for lights.

The wiring has inline "waterproof" fuses similar to this: https://www.princessauto.com/en/in-line-fuse-holder-with-led-indicator/product/PA0008684805

When I looked inside the fuse compartments (which were full of water), the fuses weren't blown, but they *were* heavily corroded, so they didn't conduct electricity.

[image]

I've replaced the fuses and cleaned the sockets/enclosures with a wire brush. Now, electricity is being conducted, as expected.

Question:

Is there anything I can do to prevent the new fuses from corroding in the future?

Comment: Aluminum is not a good choice.  Replace with brass and  grease or oil as answered.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Your solution to fuse corrosion is to replace the whole aluminum boat with a well oiled brass boat? Sounds very steampunk!

Comment: @AldusBumblebore — blacksmith37 might have meant the aluminum fuse sockets.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to clean them out. Use some vinegar to do this by soaking them in it. If you can't soak them in it, put as much as you can in the cavity of the fuse holder. Once the reactions stop, then clean it with some water and possibly a toothbrush (a used one is good ... don't steal your better half's one and put it back). Once it is all cleaned up, use some **dielectric grease** in the socket. Then once the fuse is in, coat the entire thing in a generous helping. I presume it has a cap (to make it watertight). Put it back on and clean off any excess dielectric grease. The idea is to completely fill it so no air is in there with the fuse.

The dielectric grease will pretty much arrest the corrosion, because it won't let oxygen get to the metal bits. It will also prevent water ingress. This should prevent corrosion. If it doesn't *completely* prevent it, it will keep it from happening for a long time.

Comment: @User1974 - Yes ... it does not pass electricity. That's why it works great for these types of situations. You apply it liberally and no chance of it conduction through itself and shorting something.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try silicone [plumber's grease](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08GPF597W).